# FTP put folder from command line

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ftp

I have a local folder `xxx` that I need to upload to an FTP server with a different destination `yyy` from the command line.  It could have multiple files and subfolders with more files.  It may need to create the files/folders.  What would be the FTP command for this?

I tried using `ftp-upload` but it's not working:
`fpt-upload -h ftp.blahblah.com --user uuuuu --password ppppp --dir yyy --full-path xxx`

Other attempts kept putting `xxx` within `yyy`, which I don't want.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this by installing `ncftpput` then running:

`ncftpput -R -v -u "username" -p "password" ftp.website.com ftp-upload-path local-path/*`